# Использование object-тега в html5

Tags: html, html5, internet-explorer, firefox, activex

День добрый.

Знаю, что в IE можно использовать тег object с атрибутом codebase, где можно указать заранее зарегистрированную библиотеку для обработки встроенного содержимого. А возможно ли это как-то использовать в современных браузерах на вроде chrome/firefox? Если, например, мне нужно чтобы контент прошел через какую-то библиотеку .ocx на сервере и отобразился? Пробую просто грузить страницу с заданным object и codebase - в IE показывает фрейм просмотрщика activeX (в случае pdf), а в хроме и лисе белый лист.

Задумывался пропустить файл через embed, но в нем нельзя прописать внешнюю библиотеку, зарегистрированную пользователем у себя в системе, чтобы файл обрабатывался сначала ей, а потом уже отдавался в атрибут src навроде blob содержимого. В современных браузерах это вообще разрешено?

Comment: Так на сервере или в браузере? На сервере вы можете делать что угодно, а в браузерах выполнять произвольный код запрещено ради безопасности

Comment: @andreymal библиотека регистрируется на сервере и после этого при доступе к странице сайта с object/codebase проблем с отображением из IE нет, тогда как в случае с chrome/firefox - элемент не отображается(страница грузится внутри локальной сети и обращается к codebase тоже локальным путем до сервера)

Comment: «проблем с отображением из IE нет» — ну, если вы используете ActiveX, то логично, ведь ActiveX есть только в IE, а в других браузерах его никогда не было и никогда не будет — именно ради безопасности

Comment: @andreymal а какие-то аналогичные теги для html есть, чтобы можно было пропускать контент через свою библиотеку и потом выводить? Интересует возможность именно для выведения видео и пдф файлов, через codebase входной файл модифицируется

Comment: А что мешает выполнить модификацию на стороне сервера? Зачем вы хотите затащить это именно в html?

Comment: @andreymal учитывая то что используется обязательное условие в виде пропускания файл через библиотеку - я просто не вижу других аналогов, в случае если каждый файл вызывается и изменяется лишь при запросе пользователя. Есть какие-то другие варианты?

Comment: Почему это «обязательное условие»? Что мешает отправить запрос пользователя на сервер, на сервере выполнить модификацию и отправить пользователю ответ вообще без html?

Comment: @andreymal с целью разгрузки сервера, чтобы основную работу выполняли "мощности" браузера пользователя

Comment: Ну тогда придётся или как-то портировать библиотеку под [WebAssembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/WebAssembly), или заставлять пользователя вручную устанавливать браузерное расширение и приложение-компаньон к нему, которые будут взаимодействовать друг с другом через [Native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging). В любом случае, про тег object и activex придётся забыть

Comment: object превратился в тыкву только в html5, в html4 он норма, соответственно врубаем легаси режим через `<!DOCTYPE HTML4!>` как точно пишется данный тег и сработает ли, не подскажу ибо не пользовался доктайпами. если с object не выйдет, сам файл можно подгружать с помощью `<link>` а после его же парсить js скриптом, или как сказали выше копайте в сторону WA.

Comment: @puffleeck от всех этих действий ActiveX в современных браузерах всё равно не появится

Comment: @andreymal, эммм... которого нигде кроме MS->IE никогда и не было, у всех остальных браузеров был аналог - NPAPI. p.s. почему то казалось что сам тег `<object>` умер, потому и советовал doctype...